# SELECT statement to exclude results through join table relationship

Tags: sql, select, join

Given three tables like this:

```
fruit:          taste:        fruit_taste:
id  name        id  name      id  fruit_id  taste_id
--  ----        --  ----      --  --------  --------
1   apple       1   sweet     1   1         1
2   lime        2   tart      2   1         2
3   banana                    3   2         2
4   lemon                     4   4         2
```

How can I `SELECT` only the `fruit` which do have not been identified by the join table as having a sweet `taste`? My desired results should also include 'banana', since there is not a `fruit_taste` identifying it as sweet.

I tried (along with a **ton** of other things):

```
SELECT * 
FROM fruit
LEFT OUTER JOIN fruit_taste
ON fruit_taste.fruit_id = fruit.id
WHERE (fruit_taste.taste_id != 1 OR fruit_taste.id IS null)
```

which *almost* works, but still gives me 'apple' in my result, since my apple is a Granny Smith, and is both sweet and tart. How can I exclude 'apple' in my query? Is my only option a subquery with `NOT IN`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a LEFT JOIN and avoid the subquery if you add the excluded taste to the JOIN filter and then exclude matching rows.  This should generally be better for performance than using NOT IN on a subquery, but YMMV.

```
SELECT *
FROM fruit
LEFT JOIN fruit_taste 
  ON fruit_taste.fruit_id = fruit.id
  AND fruit_taste.taste_id = 1
WHERE fruit_taste.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from fruit
where id not in
(select ft.fruit_id
from fruit_taste ft
inner join taste t
on ft.taste_id = t.id
where t.name = 'sweet')
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from using `NOT IN`, you can also use `LEFT JOIN`. To filter out fruits that have no `sweet` taste, the total number of `sweet` for every fruit should be `0`.

```
SELECT  a.ID, a.Name
FROM    fruit a
        LEFT JOIN fruit_taste b
            ON a.id = b.fruit_id
        LEFT JOIN taste c
            ON b.taste_id  = c.id
GROUP   BY a.ID, a.Name
HAVING  SUM(IFNULL(c.name = 'sweet', 0)) = 0
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1eeb/3)

Comment: This does produce the desired result (thank you), but @PinnyM's answer is much easier to understand and extend. Also, why do SQL experts insist on aliasing table names to a single letter? It makes the logic of complex conditions *so much* harder to read for novices like myself.

Comment: Although this isn't as elegant syntax-wise as what @PinnyM suggested, I ended up using this in my actual application. As it turned out, the ORM I'm using (DBIx::Class in Perl) makes it difficult to pass a parameter to a `JOIN` condition on-the-fly. Upvote coming once I have enough reputation to give it. :) Thanks again.